# Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'undefined'. TS2769

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I am adding some conditional styling depending on the the `href` type. For some reason if I add my `as` to the `Button` `styled-component` I get the TS error: `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.  TS2769`

### Component

```
interface LinkProps {
  to: string;
  target?: string;
  as?: string;
  className?: string;
  children: ReactChildren | React.ReactNode | string;
}

const Button = styled(RLink)`
  text-decoration: none;
`;

export const Link = ({
  to,
  target,
  children,
  as = 'a',
  className
}: LinkProps) => {
  return (
    <Button
      as={as}
      to={to}
      target={target}
      rel="noopener"
      className={className}
    >
      {children}
    </Button>
  );
};
```

### Without the `as`:

[image]

### WIthout the `as`:

[image]

### Full TS Error

```
index.js:1 /frontend/claim-handler/src/components/shared/Link/index.tsx
TypeScript error in /frontend/claim-handler/src/components/shared/Link/index.tsx(39,6):
This JSX tag's 'children' prop expects type 'never' which requires multiple children, but only a single child was provided.  TS2745

37 | }: LinkProps) => {
  38 |   return (
    > 39 |     <Button
           |      ^
40 |       as={as}
        41 |       to={to}
        42 |       target={target}
console.<computed> @ index.js:1
handleErrors @ webpackHotDevClient.js:174
push.../../node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js.connection.onmessage @ webpackHotDevClient.js:213


index.js:1 /frontend/claim-handler/src/components/shared/Link/index.tsx
TypeScript error in /frontend/claim-handler/src/components/shared/Link/index.tsx(40,7):
No overload matches this call.
Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Omit<Omit<import("/node_modules/@types/react-router-dom/index").LinkProps<unknown> & RefAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement> & LinkProps, never> & Partial<...>, "theme"> & { ...; } & { ...; }): ReactElement<...>', gave the following error.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.  TS2769

  38 |   return (
    39 |     <Button
    > 40 |       as={as}
      |       ^
      41 |       to={to}
      42 |       target={target}
      43 |       rel="noopener"
```

#### Edit

By removing the option as, which I don't agree with, as aren't these Types what the component expects to recieve as Props, not just arguments?

Here are the new errors:

[image]

Comment: You have `as` marked as optional,  seen as your putting a default of `a`, just take the optional `?` of `as`

Comment: Have you tried using "forwardedAs" instead of "as"? https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/1981#issuecomment-548860710

Comment: Thanks guys, see updated quesiton

Comment: Thanks for the forwardedAs suggestion, that opens up the same errors too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is you're trying to pass extremely wide type `string` to the prop accepting quite a big but still exactly defined set of strings as names of native [html tags](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/940da08/types/react/index.d.ts#L3066-L3246).
If you're going to pass as `as` prop only the names of `html` tags (i.e. not other functional or class components) you may type `as` like that:

```ts
interface LinkProps {
  to: string;
  target?: string;
  as?: keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements;
  className?: string;
  children: ReactChildren | React.ReactNode | string;
}
```

That should solve your problem.

And another minor issue.
While it's completely ok to type `children` prop yourself. That's pretty brittle way. And you have already got it wrong. [`ReactChildren`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/940da08/types/react/index.d.ts#L2956-L2963) is not a type of array of react children. That's a type of [`React.Children`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren) interface combining utility functions to work with `children` prop.

For typing `children` prop `react` exposes special helper type [`React.PropsWithChildren`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/940da08/types/react/index.d.ts#L824). And if you wish you may rewrite your code in more stable way:

```ts
import * as React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'

interface LinkProps {
    to: string;
    target?: string;
    as?: keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements;
    className?: string;
}

const Button = styled(RLink)`
    text-decoration: none;
`;

export const Link = ({
    to,
    target,
    children,
    as = 'a',
    className
}: React.PropsWithChildren<LinkProps>) => {
    return (
        <Button
            as={as}
            to={to}
            target={target}
            rel="noopener"
            className={className}
        >
            {children}
        </Button>
    );
};
```